# Appending Arrays in loop

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java code where X is a 2D array and a loop to add data to it. The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String [] args0
{
    int[] len = new int[3];
    double[][] X = null;
    double[][] vec = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the len" +(i+1)+":");
        len[i] = in.nextInt();

        if(i == 0)
        {
            vec = new double [1][len[i] + 1];
            X = new double[1][vec[0].length];
            for(int k = 0; k < vec[0].length - 1; k++)
            {
                Xi[0][k] = 0;
            }
            Xi[0][ve1[0].length-1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vec = new double [1][len[i] + 1];
            X = new double[1][vec[0].length];
            for(int k = 0; k < vec[0].length - 1; k++)
            {
                X[0][k] = 0;
            }
            X[0][vec[0].length-1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I print X, I need it have appended the values added when i=0 and when i>0. But it prints only the value of what is supposedly the final iteration. How do I make it print the data of all iterations appended to the end of data added during each iteration? I understand that since I am creating a new double[][] in each iteration, the value of gets overwritten. But how do i fix it?

Comment: I think you are missing the outer loop (iteration over the rows).

Comment: What is the purpose of the `vec` variable?

Comment: no special purpose. Just for manipulating size

Comment: @YoungHobbit: thats not a problem here

Comment: X is really just a 1D array since it never has more than 1 row. `X = new double[1][vec[0].length];` means it never has more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified that with `X = new double[1][vec[0].length];` you are always overriding the result from previous iterations. In order to fix it, you need to move the initialization out of the `for` loop. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   int[] len = new int[3];
   double[][] X = new double[3][];
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter the len " +(i+1)+":");
      len[i] = in.nextInt();

      X[i] = new double[len[i]];

      for (int j = 0; j < len[i] - 1; j++) {
         X[i][j] = 0;
      }
      X[i][len[i] - 1] = 1;
   }
   in.close();
}
```

As you can see, the array `X` is initialized in the beginning with size `3`, since it will always hold 3 one-dimensional arrays in your case. However, you can initialize the size dynamically as well. You don't need the `vec` variable, because you can always access the length that was just read and stored in `len`. In fact, you don't need the `len` array as well,  since it stores information that is anyways contained in `X`:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   double[][] X = new double[3][];
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter the len " + (i+1) + ":");

      X[i] = new double[in.nextInt()];

      for (int j = 0; j < X[i].length - 1; j++) {
         X[i][j] = 0;
      }
      X[i][X[i].length - 1] = 1;
   }
   in.close();
}
```